# Play 2.1: Call a function when an Enumerator produces a value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have an Enumerator in Play Framework 2.1. I would like to have some code executed whenever that Enumerator produces a value.

The documentation is very difficult to understand, but it seems like I need to construct an Iteratee in order to do that, but I can't find actual code that does that anywhere. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
myEnumerator.run(Iteratee.foreach[TypeToIterateOver] { msg =>
  println(msg)
})
```